# Session not working if Laravel application deployed on subdomain

Tags: session, laravel-8, session-cookies

I have a Laravel 8 application. The session is not working if deployed on the subdomain.
For example, I have a domain "`example.com`" and we have created two subdomains `testapp.example.com` and `app.example.com` for testing and staging environments.
When deploying the application on `testapp.example.com` first we observed that session not working after that updated `config/session.php` to set `session domain = ".example.com"`. Initially, it was working after this change but when again the application deployed on "`app.example.com`" session not working on testapp.example.com. It is working for "app.example.com". I want different sessions to be maintained on these different subdomains, dont want to share session between subdomain. Can anyone suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to set that session domain, that is the session_domain configuration if you wish to share the sessions across subdomains. By default it will not. You need them to be set to `app.example.com` and `testapp.example.com` accordingly. This is the `SESSION_DOMAIN` in the .env file

Alternatively you can simply change the SESSSION_COOKIE for each application. This is best set in the .env file as `SESSION_COOKIE=testexample.com` or alternatively in config/session.php if you already modified the default laravel settings in there.